How to train neural network model with large txt files in python using TensorFlow?
I've build a model with 65 input neurons and 4880 output neurons. My training data is stored in two large text files: 'X_train.txt' contains lines where each line represents a list of 65 numbers, and 'Y_train.txt' contains lines where each line represents an index number. I need to perform one-hot encoding on 'Y_train' to create a list with 4880 zeros and a single '1' at the specified index.
Due to the size of these files, I want to train my model in batches. How can I effectively train my model with these txt files in Python using TensorFlow?
so I tried to get these files tried to convert these files to variables with
with open(xPath, 'r') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        x_train.append(eval(line.strip()))  
        line = file.readline()
x_train = np.array(x_train)

but since the files are too big it takes too much time, it is not the main problem I can wait but the main problem is it uses too much memory...

Hi ba@s,To handle large datasets that are stored in text files and perform batch training in TensorFlow. tf.data.Dataset is the one that helps to load and process the data in a memory-efficient manner.It helps to load data in batches and You can use tf.data.TextLineDataset to read large text files line by line without loading the entire dataset into memory.
